# How to stop the task scheduled in java.util.Timer class

Tags: java, timer

I am using `java.util.Timer` class and I am using its schedule method to perform some task, but after executing it for 6 times I have to stop its task.

How should I do that?

Comment: Update: The `Timer` and `TimerTask` classes have been supplanted, as noted in their Javadoc. Learn to use the *Executors* framework added to Java 5+. See [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) by Oracle.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Keep a reference to the timer somewhere, and use:

```
timer.cancel();
timer.purge();
```

to stop whatever it's doing. You could put this code inside the task you're performing with a `static int` to count the number of times you've gone around, e.g.

```
private static int count = 0;
public static void run() {
     count++;
     if (count >= 6) {
         timer.cancel();
         timer.purge();
         return;
     }

     ... perform task here ....

}
```

Comment: I think cancel is enough, don't need to have purge

Comment: is it good to add timer.cancel() in  final according to ( Effetive Java book)

Comment: @Jacky it's good practice to have both, but theoretically `cancel` itself would work.

Comment: @Jacky is right. Look at the implementation of Timer. Calling purge after cancel is absolutely useless. Cancel clears the whole task list, while the purge iterates over the same list, checks if the status is CANCELED and then removes the tasks.

Comment: Calling cancel() on Timer itself will cancel ALL tasks done on that timer. That is a bad idea, because usually one would use a single Timer instance for multiple timed tasks. It is important to use a single Timer because a Timer is expensive: it allocates a thread. The correct answer is to retain a reference to a Timer*Task* and call cancel on that because that terminates just that instance and leaves the rest intact.

Comment: if the activity/fragment that started the Timer is destroyed or stopped, does the Timer scheduled stop on its own?

Answer (score 65):

Either call [`cancel()` on the `Timer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel()) if that's all it's doing, or [`cancel()` on the `TimerTask`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel()) if the timer itself has other tasks which you wish to continue.

Answer (score 40):

You should stop the task that you have scheduled on the timer:
Your timer:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do something
    };
};
t.schedule(tt,1000,1000);
```

In order to stop:

```
tt.cancel();
t.cancel(); //In order to gracefully terminate the timer thread
```

Notice that just cancelling the timer will not terminate ongoing timertasks.

Answer (score 2):

Terminate the Timer once after awake at a specific time in milliseconds.

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
             public void run() {
             System.out.println(" Run spcific task at given time.");
             t.cancel();
             }
 }, 10000);
```