# Timer stop after one minute

Tags: android

I made a Timer and I want to stop it when it reaches to 60 seconds(1 min).

here's the code:

```
        Timer t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    myTextView.setText("timer=" + String.valueOf(TimeCounter));
                    TimeCounter++;
                }
               });
            }
    }, 0, 1000);  
    int I=60;
    if (TimeCounter == I) { 
          -------------- stop the timer here ----------------
       }
       }
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will probably need to move the stopping condition inside your task... so it looks more less like this:

```
final Timer t = new Timer();
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (TimeCounter == I) {
                    t.cancel();
                    return;
                }

                myTextView.setText("timer=" + String.valueOf(TimeCounter));
                TimeCounter++;
            }
           });
        }
}, 0, 1000);
```

Remember to define earlier:

```
int I=60;
```

Also, you would probably need to mark Timer as final (just as I did in code).

Comment: TY!!! the timer stops at 59, I need it to stop at 60 so ill put the int I=61; and I will add t.purge();

Comment: yea, you're right... i edited the code so it stops at 60 if you set I to 60. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

try below code to stop timer :-

```
if (TimeCounter == I) { 
          t.cancel();
       }
```

also see below link:-

[How to stop immediately the task scheduled in Java.util.Timer class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050442/how-to-stop-immediately-the-task-scheduled-in-java-util-timer-class)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CountDownTimer, maybe this is a simpler solution:

```
      int Time = 0;

      public class OneMinuteCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

       public OneMinuteCountDownTimer (long startTime, long interval) {

      super(startTime, interval);
    }

  @Override
  public void onFinish() {

             myTextView.setText("timer="+Time+" time finished");
             Time=0;
  }

  @Override
  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             Time++;
         myTextView.setText("timer="+Time);
  }
 }

}
```

Make the CountDownTimer global and call it when You want to start the CountDownTimer:

```
       private OneMinuteCountDownTimer countDownTimer;
       private final long startTime = 60 * 1000;
       private final long interval = 1 * 1000;
```

### inside onCreate (EDIT):

```
       countDownTimer = new OneMinuteCountDownTimer(startTime,interval);

       countDownTimer.start();
```

and cancel it, if You want to cancel it before one minute:

```
       countDownTimer.cancel();
```

Comment: I put the 1st code at the: 

"public class FirstActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {  "

the 2nd code privates at the place of all the privates, 

and the "countDownTimer.start();" code at the "public void onCreate, "

my app crashing at start..

Comment: see my edit, maybe You have forgotten to initialize the countdowntimer

Comment: Someone helped me but a countdown is better then a regular timer for me so I will try it :) ty.

Comment: if You got any problems, come back :)