# My java class Updater don't update

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I would like to know where is the problem in this class, I'm making a class that every n seconds make something, but it appear to do it only 1 time.
this is the class

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Updater {
    private Timer timer;
    public Updater(int seconds){
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new UpdaterTask(), seconds*1000);
    }
    class UpdaterTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(Math.random());
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the test

```
public class TestUpdater {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Updater(1);
    }
}
```

i think that this test have to give me a random number every second but after the first second the process terminate.
Sorry for the bad english and thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `schedule(task, delay)` only execute the task once. `schedule(task, delay, period)` execute the task repeatedly with fixed delay.

   ```
   timer.schedule(new UpdaterTask(), 0, seconds * 1000)
   ```
2. Remove `cancel()`

   ```
   // timer.cancel();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

When your `main()` thread terminates the application also terminates.

Just add `Thread.sleep(10000)` at the end of your code. It will then work for 10 seconds.

**AND**

Consult [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409116/how-to-stop-the-task-scheduled-in-java-util-timer-class) for how to use the cancel method. I think you did not want to use it there.

**AND**

Change the scheduling type, use

`timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new UpdaterTask(), 0, seconds*1000);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to comment out, the `timer.cancel()` call. This is making the timer itself stop after the first execution of its timer task.

Then for repeated execution, you should call `scheduleAtFixedRate` method, with `delay == 0`, to start the task immediately, and `period == x seconds`, to run it every `x seconds`.

```
class Updater {
    private Timer timer;
    public Updater(int seconds){
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new UpdaterTask(), 0, seconds*1000); // use scheduleAtFixedRate method
    }
    class UpdaterTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(Math.random());
            //timer.cancel(); --> comment this line
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the difference between scheduleAtFixedRate and simple schedule?