# Everything in my game starts going double speed when I start a new game. Can't stop the timer

Tags: java, timer, delay

I am doing a Snake clone and everything goes fine before I start a new game. Everything works then too but everything is also double speed! I think this is because there are two timers working same time doing same functions? I don't find a way how to deal with this. This is what my timer looks like and as you can see, it is quite messy :/ Don't even try to figure out it all. My snake consists balls and most of the code tracks their movement.

```
public class Draw extends JPanel implements KeyListener{

static ArrayList x = new ArrayList(); //the x coordinates of balls
static ArrayList y = new ArrayList(); //the y coordinates of balls
static int x_val=15; // movement x-axis
static int y_val=0; // movement y-axis
static boolean ballCoordinatesDone = false; //initialize balls
static int score = 0; 
static boolean snakeCrashed = false; //if snake has crashed (stop)
static boolean highscoresOpened = false; //if highscores are opened already (don't repeat)

static int foodx = 0; //food x coordinate
static int foody = 0; //food y coordinate


Timer  t = new Timer(150, new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(snakeCrashed == false){
        if(ballCoordinatesDone == false){
        ballCoordinates();
        }
        ballCoordinatesDone = true;

        int lastX = Integer.parseInt((String) x.get(x.size()-1)); //gets x coodinate for first ball
        int lastY = Integer.parseInt((String) y.get(y.size()-1)); //gets y coodinate for first ball
        int a;

//checks if snake collides with itself
        for(a=0; a < x.size(); a++){

            if(lastX + x_val == Integer.parseInt((String) x.get(a)) && lastY + y_val == Integer.parseInt((String) y.get(a))){

                snakeCrashed = true;

            }
        }

//checks if snake goes out of bounds
        if(lastX + x_val < 5  || lastY + y_val < 50 || lastX + x_val >= 310  || lastY + y_val >= 355  ){

            snakeCrashed = true;

        }else{

//adds a new ball in direction of movement (new head)
        x.add("" + (lastX + x_val));
        y.add("" + (lastY + y_val));

        }

//checks if you hit a food
        if(lastX + x_val == foodx && lastY + y_val == foody){

            foodRandomizer();
            score+=10;

        }else{
 //removes the tail     
            if(snakeCrashed == false){
            x.remove(0);
            y.remove(0);
            }

        }

        repaint();

//if snakeCrashed == true   
        }else{
            if(highscoresOpened == false){ 
            CreateGUI.highscoreFrame(); 
            highscoresOpened = true;
            t.stop();


            }
        }
    }

});
```

Then the CreateGUI.highscoreFrame has a button called newGame that looks like this:

```
JButton newGame = new JButton("New Game");
    newGame.setBounds(75,300,100,40);
    newGame.setVisible(true);
    newGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            hsFrame.setVisible(false);
            hsFrame.dispose();
            submitHSFrame.setVisible(false);
            submitHSFrame.dispose();
            snake.setVisible(false);
            snake.dispose();
            Draw.snakeCrashed = false;
            Draw.highscoresOpened = false;
            Draw.x.clear();
            Draw.y.clear();
            Draw.score = 0;
            Draw.x_val=15;
            Draw.y_val=0;
            Draw.ballCoordinatesDone = false;
            Draw.score = 0;

            CreateGUI ng = new CreateGUI();

        }
    }); 

    hsFrame.add(newGame);
```

Comment: Use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409116/how-to-stop-the-task-scheduled-in-java-util-timer-class

Comment: You haven't posted an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so it's going to be a little hard to help you. But when do you create the second Timer? Why don't you just not create the second timer?

Comment: @user270349 That was more a rhetorical question intended to get the OP thinking about debugging his own program.

Comment: The method cancel() is undefined for the type Timer. I am using a Swing timer. There is no such command. And Kevin, thanks for trying to help but I kinda know the problem but I am a beginner with no idea how to fix or debug it. I've tried for hours now.

Comment: For some reason it started to work with "t.removeActionListener()", why doesn't it work with t.stop();?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Draw object creates a new timer so you have the game running n times at the same time but the copies of the game share the state because ir is stored in static variables so the state is updated n-1 times faster than it should.

You may stop the timer [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409116/how-to-stop-the-task-scheduled-in-java-util-timer-class) or you may use a static timer and [schedule/cancel the task](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) each time.